# I cant click/find elements in Google Meet when using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, google-meet

**Getting to Meeting:**

```
from time import sleep

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
})
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'../Other Projects/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
febxp = driver.find_element_by_xpath


def Rmunify():
    # Goes to RmUnify
    driver.get('https://sts.platform.rmunify.com/Account/SignIn?ReturnUrl=%252fissue%252fwsfed%252fwww%253fwa%253dwsignin1.0%2526wtrealm%253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252flaunchpad.platform.rmunify.com%25252frp%2526wctx%253drm%25253d0%252526id%25253dpassive%252526ru%25253d%2525252f%2526wct%253d2020-10-20T13%25253a09%25253a46Z%2526wreply%253dhttps%25253a%25252f%25252fwww.rmunify.com%25252f')
    # Types email
    febxp("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/input").send_keys("")
    # Types password
    febxp("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/input").send_keys("")
    # Presses Sign In
    febxp("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/input").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    # Goes to classroom main page
    driver.get("https://classroom.google.com/a/chace.enfield.sch.uk")
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    # Presses Verify
febxp("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    # Select the class
    input("Press once class is selected: ")
    febxp("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/a").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)


def Main():
    # Turns mic off
    # febxp(
    #     "/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div").click()
    # # Turns Camera off
    # febxp(
    #     "/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div").click()
    # # Joins call
    # febxp(
    #     "/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    # Go to main part to say goodbye
    while True:
        try:
            Choice = input("What to do? (G, C): ")
            elif Choice.lower() == "c":
                # Goes to chat
                febxp("/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]").click()
```

**Where the problem occours:**

```
                # Goes to chat
                febxp("/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]").click()
```

**And gives the error:**

```
    febxp("/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]").click()
  File "C:\Users\Diaboli Sica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Diaboli Sica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Diaboli Sica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Diaboli Sica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
```

**Problem:**
I use selenium to join a google meet. it asks for input and when I press enter it should press the chat button. but it gives the error saying it can't find the element even though I can see it there and then.  I have tried every method possible. I tried looking for the class, looking for tags, everything. sometimes it would find an element (I don't know if it was the right 1) but can't click it... I have tried looking and clicking on other elements and still nothing. it only happens as soon as I go to google meet, I can't even press the mute button before joining the class.

**Extra Info:**

- The button is a div but has "role='button'", the rest are spans and divs.
- The random XPATHs bunched together were to try different ways to find the button.\n
- I have tried using XPATHs, stuff like //something[@something=''], class names, tag names but none work.\n
- I have checked for iframes but I am pretty sure it does not use an iframe.

Inspect element image:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/wohx5.png

Inspect element XPATH:

- `/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]`

Inspect element HTML:

- `<div jsshadow="" role="button" class="uArJ5e UQuaGc kCyAyd QU4Gid foXzLb IeuGXd M9Bg4d" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef" jsname="VyLmyb" aria-label="Show everyone" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" data-tooltip="Show everyone" aria-expanded="false" data-tab-id="1" data-tooltip-vertical-offset="-12" data-tooltip-horizontal-offset="0"><div class="Fvio9d MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><div class="e19J0b CeoRYc"></div><span jsslot="" class="l4V7wb Fxmcue"><span class="NPEfkd RveJvd snByac"><div class="ZaI3hb"><div class="gV3Svc"><span class="DPvwYc sm8sCf azXnTb" aria-hidden="true"><svg focusable="false" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="Hdh4hc cIGbvc NMm5M"><path d="M15 8c0-1.42-.5-2.73-1.33-3.76.42-.14.86-.24 1.33-.24 2.21 0 4 1.79 4 4s-1.79 4-4 4c-.43 0-.84-.09-1.23-.21-.03-.01-.06-.02-.1-.03A5.98 5.98 0 0 0 15 8zm1.66 5.13C18.03 14.06 19 15.32 19 17v3h4v-3c0-2.18-3.58-3.47-6.34-3.87zM9 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2m0 9c-2.7 0-5.8 1.29-6 2.01V18h12v-1c-.2-.71-3.3-2-6-2M9 4c2.21 0 4 1.79 4 4s-1.79 4-4 4-4-1.79-4-4 1.79-4 4-4zm0 9c2.67 0 8 1.34 8 4v3H1v-3c0-2.66 5.33-4 8-4z"></path></svg></span><span jscontroller="FTBAv" jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md;L6tSXb:B6c1Fe" class="wnPUne N0PJ8e">7</span></div></div></span></span></div>`

Inspect element selector

- `#ow3 > div.T4LgNb > div > div:nth-child(5) > div.crqnQb > div.pHsCke > div.Jrb8ue > div > div.NzPR9b > div.uArJ5e.UQuaGc.kCyAyd.QU4Gid.foXzLb.IeuGXd.M9Bg4d`

I have been trying all day and could not find a solution to anything else.

Comment: Do you think you could only provide the code that is causing the issue instead of the whole file? What output is the code currently returning? Instead of using time.sleep() you might be better served using driver.implicitly_wait()

Comment: Have you checked whether it uses iframes, sometimes requires to be on the right iframe. Just a minor hint.

Comment: @JoshZwiebel I added the error it gives, changed the sleep(), and separated the error code from the code

Comment: @pafede2 From what I have checked, it does not seem to be in an iframe, iv tried checking every way if it was but I'm pretty sure it is not.

Comment: You only have to set implicitly wait once and it is set for the lifetime of the driver. but that doesnt solve your issue separate point. You are also using explicit xpaths instead of a search. This is very brittle. Can you show what your inspect element looks like? Its possible you are missing the element by one div or something because of how specific your xpath query is

Comment: @JoshZwiebel I just added the image of the element, the XPath, the HTML, and the selector of it.

Comment: Can you try running selenium in headful mode. I would be worried that the html you're seeing on your browser with your settings and cookies might not be the same as an automated fresh chrome instance. You should try to see what selenium is seeing and why it is missing it

Comment: @JoshZwiebel 1) what is selenium headful mode? I try searching for it on google but can't find anything on it. 2) What does a headful mode do?

Comment: I think I may have made up the term to mean the opposite of headless. As in let selenium open the browser and you can see it looking for elements and performing the actions. Set a debug breakpoint right before u have an error. You'll be on the page where you are looking for the element you want. Them you should be able to see what html element selenium is seeing that you are not

Comment: If not headless mode, how would I activate 'headful' mode? and how would I use it? also, how would I set a "debug breakpoint"?

Comment: @JoshZwiebel sorry, i forgot to @ you in the previous comment

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = Chrome(options=options)

This will make sure selenium is running in headful mode. And by debug breakpoint I just mean a breakpoint in your code. Just like you would debug anything else

Comment: @JoshZwiebel so I put on headful mode and made it so it errors out when it fails and I ran the code (and it failed bc it could not click the thing). what should I do now?

Comment: Are you getting the same error. The point of this exercise is to make sure you're searching for the same html selenium is seeing. You should use inspect element in selenium's automated chrome tab and verify. Don't let your code error out. Set a breakpoint the line before it does

Comment: @JoshZwiebel Ok so I have put it into headless=false, I have set a breakpoint before the line of code that errors, I checked whether it was on the page before the code was executed and it was. I updated the error log to be the full log.